# About UIViews delegate

Tags: ios5, uiview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

My question is quite simple but no way to find a simple exemple on internet.
I have a main view controller with buttons and i'd like to display an UIView created with IB when i click on a button, so for exemple:

-ViewController (.h/.m/.xib) is my main interface with a menu button

-MenuView (.h/.m/.xib) is my view that i would like to be displayed as a pop up window over my uiviewcontroller.

So how is it possible to control my MenuView from my viewController ? Is it possible to create it with IB or is it better to make it programmatically? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for a way to do this only with interface builder, but the IB can help you. I will do it creating another view controller which contains the view you want to be shown. On your already existing view controller you can create a method i.e:

```
- (void) show: (id) sender {
    UIViewController *theNewController = [TheNewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"TheNewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self presentViewController:theNewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and link this method, using the IB, to the button actions.(right click on the button in IB, choose the event i.e Touch Down, drag'n drop to the File's Owner). But I recommend you also seeing view controller's apple documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html